# Running bash script from Processing

Tags: bash, processing

I have a bash script called lightmeter.sh that creates/overwrites a text document called lightstuff.txt. Here is the code for that:

```
#!/bin/bash          
      gphoto2 --get-config=lightmeter 1> lightstuff.txt
```

I've started to write a processing script to execute the bash script:

```
    void setup() {


       String[] args = {"sh","","/Users/lorenzimmer/Documents/RC/Camera_control/first_scripts/lightmeter.sh"};
exec(args); 
}
```

When I run the program the script does not execute, or it doesn't update the text file like it does when I run it from the terminal.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Loren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how I run Bash scripts in Processing (a [more complete version is here](https://github.com/jeffThompson/ProcessingTeachingSketches/blob/master/Utilities/RunUnixCommands/RunUnixCommands.pde)):

```
// required imports that aren't loaded by default
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

void setup() {
  String commandToRun = "./yourBashScript.sh";

  // where to do it - should be full path
  File workingDir = new File(sketchPath(""));

  // run the script!
  String returnedValues;
  try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToRun, null, workingDir);
    int i = p.waitFor();
    if (i == 0) {
      BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      while ( (returnedValues = stdInput.readLine ()) != null) {
        println(returnedValues);
      }
    }

    // if there are any error messages but we can still get an output, they print here
    else {
      BufferedReader stdErr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
      while ( (returnedValues = stdErr.readLine ()) != null) {
        println(returnedValues);
      }
    }
  }

  // if there is any other error, let us know
  catch (Exception e) {
    println("Error running command!");
    println(e);
    // e.printStackTrace(); // a more verbose debug, if needed
  }
}
```

Comment: This did work like it was supposed to (I think) however, I'm using a program called gphoto2 to execute some commands for my camera.  When processing runs the lines with the gphoto2 commands it throws an error.  Any thoughts on a work around?  gphoto2: http://gphoto.org/

Comment: I have a sinking feeling that the problem is between gphoto2 and my camera.  When ever I run the commands that worked last Saturday at the command prompt now throw errors.  Stand by.

Comment: Ok, but in the meantime, since this did solve your question, you can accept the answer to close it. :)